# Parsing XML Error Duplicate Atrributes

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I've tried so many solutions I've about given up with it. I'm getting two xml parsing errors that keep popping up after cleaning the project, making a new project, or re-importing the project. Nothing seems to work. It has to do with the layout xml and some data binding xml of the same name but it just keeps loading the data binding xml that's in the build folder and it seems a debug location and giving me the errors.

Here's my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable name="user" type ="com.example.chave.utclinicalnursing.signUpActivity"/>
    </data>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_sign_up"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.example.chave.utclinicalnursing.signUpActivity"
        android:background="#11336A"
        android:weightSum="1">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="381dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/titleView"
            android:layout_weight="0.04"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/fNameTitle"
                android:text="First Name"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="85dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/lNameTitle"
                android:text="Last Name"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="381dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/titleView2"
            android:layout_weight="0.13">


            <EditText
                android:layout_width="174dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textCapWords|textPersonName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:backgroundTint="#DD6A20" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textCapWords|textPersonName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:backgroundTint="#DD6A20" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:text="Email"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:backgroundTint="#DD6A20" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:text="Enter A Password"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText7"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:backgroundTint="#DD6A20" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:text="Confirm Password"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText8"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:backgroundTint="#DD6A20" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="242dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:text="Enter Your ID Provided By UT"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText9"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:backgroundTint="#DD6A20"
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" />

        <TextView
            android:text="What Are You?"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="185dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner_item"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:popupBackground="#DD6A20"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

        <Button
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/signIn"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#DD6A20"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <Button
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/signIn2"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#DD6A20"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="An administator must approve your registration before you are able to sign in to your account"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/titleView3"
            android:layout_weight="0.41"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:text="Already Have Account?"
                android:layout_width="196dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

            <TextView
                android:text="Log In"
                android:layout_width="84dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#DD6A20"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold|italic"
                android:onClick="startLoginActivity"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Here's the data binding xml that gives the errors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_sign_up"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.chave.utclinicalnursing.signUpActivity"
    android:background="#11336A"
    android:weightSum="1" 
    android:tag="layout/activity_sign_up_0" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="381dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/titleView"
        android:layout_weight="0.04"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fNameTitle"
            android:text="First Name"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="85dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lNameTitle"
            android:text="Last Name"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="381dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/titleView2"
        android:layout_weight="0.13">


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="174dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textCapWords|textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:backgroundTint="#DD6A20" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textCapWords|textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:backgroundTint="#DD6A20" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText6"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:backgroundTint="#DD6A20" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:text="Enter A Password"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText7"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:backgroundTint="#DD6A20" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:text="Confirm Password"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText8"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:backgroundTint="#DD6A20" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="242dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:text="Enter Your ID Provided By UT"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText9"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:backgroundTint="#DD6A20"
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" />

    <TextView
        android:text="What Are You?"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="185dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner_item"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:popupBackground="#DD6A20"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/signIn"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="#DD6A20"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/signIn2"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="#DD6A20"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="An administator must approve your registration before you are able to sign in to your account"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/titleView3"
        android:layout_weight="0.41"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:text="Already Have Account?"
            android:layout_width="196dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="Log In"
            android:layout_width="84dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#DD6A20"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold|italic"
            android:onClick="startLoginActivity"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What is causing the parsing xml errors?

Here's the log output:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateReleaseSources, :app:prepareReleaseUnitTestDependencies, :app:mockableAndroidJar]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkReleaseManifest 
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE 
:app:prepareComAndroidDatabindingAdapters121Library UP-TO-DATE 
:app:prepareComAndroidDatabindingLibrary121Library UP-TO-DATE 
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2421Library UP-TO-DATE 
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72421Library UP-TO-DATE 
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72421Library UP-TO-DATE 
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2421Library UP-TO-DATE 
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72421Library UP-TO-DATE 
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2421Library UP-TO-DATE 
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2421Library UP-TO-DATE 
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2421Library UP-TO-DATE 
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2421Library UP-TO-DATE 
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2421Library UP-TO-DATE 
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42421Library UP-TO-DATE 
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2421Library UP-TO-DATE 
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies :app:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE 
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE 
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE 
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE 
:app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE 
:app:mergeReleaseResources 
:app:dataBindingProcessLayoutsRelease 
:app:processReleaseManifest 
:app:processReleaseResources 
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error parsing XML: duplicate attribute","sources":[{"file":"D:\\Android\\Android Projects\\UTClinicalNursing\\app\\build\\intermediates\\data-binding-layout-out\\release\\layout\\activity_sign_up.xml","position":{"startLine":22}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
D:\Android\Android Projects\UTClinicalNursing\app\build\intermediates\data-binding-layout-out\release\layout\activity_sign_up.xml:23: error: Error parsing XML: duplicate attribute



FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Can you show the error log?

Comment: @klauskpm as in the event log or a logcat? or the messages?

Comment: The errors messages shown in the log, from Android.

Comment: @klauskpm sorry if this isn't what you wanted. Kind of new to this

Comment: Could be that you are using `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` two times in the same tag.

Answer (score 2):

Answer is in the comments, like @klauskpm wrote.

"you are using xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" two times in the same tag."